# compilation avoidance in the new Gradle plugin for Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, compilation

I've got a question to the "Compilation avoidance" improvement coming in
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/2-5-alpha-gradle-plugin

I assume that from one build to another some already compiled code is stored and, if not changed, will be used for a future compilation again. Where are the compiled binaries stored? is it going to be "build" directory of the project or somewhere in Gradle caches?

I wonder if this can speed up performance of my build server. The current set up is to clean the workspace of a job before building, therefore the cached classes would be erased...

thanks in advance for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoidance is not caching. Avoidance is to avoid to re-compile what didn't change. I suggest you read the excellent article on the topic from Gradle: https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance

Comment: thanks for the reply, you've linked this topic instead of the article or?

Comment: I fixed the link. Thx